# C# Class Instantiation from string

Tags: c#

I have a class name which i receive in string so i have to instantiate the class and do the stuff. i can instantiate the class using following code but how can I cast the instance to my actual class name which is stored in string???

```
string serviceObjectToInstantiate = shared.GetServiceName(screenName) + ", Prefill Service";
var objectType = Type.GetType(serviceObjectToInstantiate);
var service = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
```

(how to cast to actual class which is dynamic and stored in string).
please help..

Comment: Why do you need to cast?

Comment: I am not able to use service object directly like cannot use any method or property.

Comment: var service = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
after the above line i want say service.<methodname> or service.propertyName but i am not getting anything so I thought createinstance must be of some type.

Comment: You don't know the type at compile time. How would you know what methods or properties there are. You can find out through reflection but what is won? Do you expect them to implement an interface?

Comment: @user3395226 and why do you think that `propertyName` will exist on this object type? Do all of them implement some interface or have some parent common ancestor?

Comment: Can `dynamic` be used here?

Comment: i know propertyName exists coz there is only service and i have to use in n number of forms. so rather than instantiating in every form I am writing common class where I will pass some variable and call this service. in this way i wont have to repeat the code in every form. rather i will call execute this service via common class in my form.

Comment: @user3395226 so you actually have only one type?

Comment: yes thats right. i have only one type.

Comment: Yes, [we can](https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2019/02/11/instantiating-a-c-object-from-a-string-using-activator-createinstance-in-net/) use `dynamic` here.

Comment: @user3395226 so why just not instantiate it directly in your common class and call it?

Comment: using dynamic keyword helped. working fine.. thx everyone...

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast to anything meaningful because you don't know type at runtime, unless all your services implement some interface or have some parent common ancestor, then you cast to it and you can access it properties/methods.

If your services does not have common ground but you expect them to have property/method with specific name you can do some reflection magic like this:

```
class MyService
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }     
}

var x = typeof(MyService).GetProperty("MyProperty")
    .GetGetMethod()
    .Invoke(new MyService { MyProperty = 5}, null); // sets x to 5
```

Though reflection is quite expensive and you can improve performance by using [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) creating lambda and caching it somehow(but i would check against caching just MethodInfo):

```
var type = typeof(MyService);
var method = type.GetProperty(nameof(MyService.MyProperty)).GetGetMethod();
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
var call = Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(param, type),  method);
// this func should be cached
var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, int>>(call, param).Compile(); 
var x = func(new MyService { MyProperty = 5}); // sets x to 5
```

Answer (score 0):

**dynamic** keyword helped. rather than using 
var service = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
I used 
dynamic service = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
as suggested by Dialecticus

Reference
[https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2019/02/11/instantiating-a-c-object-from-a-string-using-activator-createinstance-in-net/][1]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, you know the class name in string, want to create an instance through reflection?

class define:

```
namespace DynamicPriceProjectV2
{
     class Program
     {.....}
}
```

in a mothod:

```
string programType = "DynamicPriceProjectV2.Program";
var programObj = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(programType);
```